# Dropwizard intercept bad json and return custom error message

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I want to intercept a bad JSON input and return custom error messages using Dropwizard application. I followed the approach of defining a custom exception mapper as mentioned here : http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/ . But it did not work for me. This same question has been asked here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/r76Ny-pCveA but unanswered.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

My code below and I am registering it in dropwizard as environment.jersey().register(RuntimeExceptionMapper.class);

```
@Provider
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuntimeExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RuntimeException runtime) {
        logger.error("API invocation failed. Runtime : {}, Message : {}", runtime, runtime.getMessage());
        return Response.serverError().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(new Error()).build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1:

The exception being thrown by Jackson doesn't extends `RuntimeException`, but it *does* extend `Exception`. This doesn't matter though. (See Problem 2)

### Problem 2:

[`DropwizardResourceConfig`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-jersey/0.7.1/io/dropwizard/jersey/DropwizardResourceConfig.java#DropwizardResourceConfig), registers it's own [`JsonProcessingExceptionMapper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-jersey/0.7.1/io/dropwizard/jersey/jackson/JsonProcessingExceptionMapper.java#JsonProcessingExceptionMapper). So you should already see results similar to

```
{
    "message":"Unrecognized field \"field\" (class d.s.h.c.MyClass),..."
}
```

Now if you want to override this, then you should create a more specific exception mapper. When working with exception mappers the most specific one will be chosen. `JsonProcessingException` is subclassed by `JsonMappingException` and `JsonProcessingException`, so you will want to create an exception mapper for each of these. Then register them. I am not sure how to unregister the Dropwizard `JsonProcessingExceptionMapper`, otherwise we could just create a mapper for `JsonProcessingException`, which will save us the hassle of create both.

### Update

So you *can* remove the Dropwizard mapper, if you want, with the following

```
Set<Object> providers = environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getSingletons();
Iterator it = providers.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object val = it.next();
    if (val instanceof JsonProcessingExceptionMapper) {
        it.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you are free to use your own mapper, `JsonProcessingException`